# How to create a LocalDateTime variable having the instant hour, minutes and seconds from a LocalDate variable?

Tags: java

There is a `LocalDate` variable :

```
TMmcParametrage parametrageDateLogicielle = parametrageRepository.getEntityManager().find(TMmcParametrage.class, "DATE_LOGICIELLE");
LocalDate dateLogiciel = LocalDate.parse(parametrageDateLogicielle.getValeur());
```

LocalDate lacks the hours, minutes and seconds parts. How to construct a `LocalDateTime` from dateLogiciel having the current hour, minutes and seconds ?

Comment: `LocalDateTime.parse` takes a parameter that can be parsed. As the javadoc describes: "Obtains an instance of LocalDateTime from a text string such as 2007-12-03T10:15:30." So if you provide a string in that format it should parse fine.

Comment: As I am not aware of what the `TMmcParametrage` class does, it is hard to provide any additional help.

Comment: don't think you can. After all, LocalDate doesn't keep the time, only year, month and day. You can add a LocalTime yourself, but if it's supposed to be the time of creation of that LocalDate, it won't match.

Comment: @Stultuske I want to add localtime

Comment: [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) has a few methods to convert to a `LocalDateTime`. And [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) itself has factory methods that can take both the date and time.

Comment: @pheromix I understand that, but the point is: you've registered the LocalDate. Do you want the time of the moment you registered that LocalDate? If yes, that 's not possible, unless you've also registered that Time somewhere. You can add a self-specified Time, or use the atStartOfDay, but those won't match the Time when the LocalDate was created. That information isn't there anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get a local time object with now then construct a LocalDateTime with the [of(LocalDate, LocalTime)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#of-java.time.LocalDate-java.time.LocalTime-) method.

```java
LocalDate dateLogiciel = ...
LocalTime time = LocalTime.now(); 
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(dateLogiciel, time);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`atTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#atTime(java.time.LocalTime)) to get a `LocalDateTime`. You should pass in a `LocalTime` represents the current time. Note that "the current time" depends on the current time zone. You should decide which time zone's "current time" you want.

```
LocalDateTime datetime = dateLogiciel.atTime(
    // replace ZoneOffset.UTC with the desired ZoneId
    LocalTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

*How to create a LocalDateTime variable having the instant hour, minutes and seconds from a LocalDate variable?*

As an addition to [aled's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77613305/1552534) answer, you can correct the time granularity to seconds as follows:

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now();
System.out.println(ld);
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(ld,LocalTime.now()).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
System.out.println(ldt);
```

prints

```
2023-12-06
2023-12-06T11:32:07
```